# Get JSON value from an file in a arranged format in linux without using JQ command

Tags: python, linux

My JSON file:

```
[{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "Article"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "Sellable_UOM"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "PriceFamilyCode"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "PriceFamilyDescription"},
{"type": "STRING","name": "SalesDistrict"},
{"type": "DATE","name": "FiscalWeekendDate"}]
```

Expected Result:

```
Article,NULLABLE,STRING
Sellable_UOM,NULLABLE,STRING
PriceFamilyCode,NULLABLE,STRING
PriceFamilyDescription,NULLABLE,STRING
SalesDistrict,NULLABLE,STRING
FiscalWeekendDate,NULLABLE,DATE
```

I require the result in the rearranged order and also if in case the json file dosent contain the mode then it should be replaced by the "NULLABLE" value in the end result.

I was able to achive this theoufh below command:

```
echo $schema | sed s/{/\\n{/g |jq -r '.[] |[ .name, .type, .mode //"NULLABLE"]|@csv' | sed s/'"'//g
```

But due to some reson the JQ command is not supported in some of my cloud build,
so can anyone help me in achieving this result without using JQ command in linux or Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work.

```py
cat yourjsonfile.json | python3 -c 'import json; import sys; payload = json.load(sys.stdin); bits = [[value["name"], value.get("mode", "NULLABLE"), value["type"]] for value in payload]; [print(",".join(bit))for bit in bits]'
```

Here is that python3 code nicely formatted:

```py
import json
import sys

payload = json.load(sys.stdin)
bits = [[value["name"], value.get("mode", "NULLABLE"), value["type"]] for value in payload]

# Using a list comprehension to get a one line for loop, not sure how to do it otherwise.
[print(",".join(bit))for bit in bits]
```